# django модель user

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь добавить новые поля к модели users, чтобы пользователь имел аватарку

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', verbose_name='Изображение')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile


class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Доп. информация'


# Определяем новый класс настроек для модели User
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInline, )


# Перерегистрируем модель User
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

views.py

```
def kabinet(request):
    dos = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    return render(request, 'accounts/kabinet.html')
```

Мой шаблон не могу получать картинку

Как правильно передать значение в шаблон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, подключенное по умолчанию `AuthenticationMiddleware` добавляет модель текущего пользователя к `request`, а подключенный по умолчанию контекстный процессор `auth` делает переменную `user` доступной в шаблоне, так что выбирать его из базы не нужно:

```
def kabinet(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/kabinet.html')
```

Во-вторых, если хотите что-то передать в контекст шаблона, передайте это в словаре третьим параметром функции [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
return render(request, 'accounts/kabinet.html', {'greeting': 'Hello!'})
```

Наконец, доступ к аватарке в шаблоне можно получить так:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <img src="{{ user.userprofile.avatar.url }}">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'img/default_avatar.png' %}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Огромное  спасибо вам вы мне очень сильно помогли :)